# get thread count on HP-UX

Tags: multithreading, shell, hp-ux, ps

how can I get thread count on HP-UX
I am using 
`ps -eLf| grep java | wc -l` and
`ps -L -p $PID |wc -l`
on liunx and solaris, but it seems can't use on HP-UX

I have tried `ps uH p $PID` on HP-UX, but it seems can't too.
Does any one have solution for this? 
please help ^_^

Comment: try (ps -ef | grep java) | wc -l

Comment: I think use `ps -ef |grep java` will list the process of java.but I need the thread count of java process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'ps -ef |grep -i java |wc -l '      >> is the best workaround (this will count your grep command as well, so if it results in value 'x' then total tthread in execution is 'x-1' actually. )